# Atualizar dlls no cliente

Tags: mysql, delphi

Tenho um software que se comunica com um banco de dados Mysql 4.1.14.

Instalei um novo servidor para testes Mysql 5.6, mas quando vou comunicar com o novo banco, aparece a mensagem informando que o cliente não suporta o protocolo de autenticação requisitado pelo servidor. Considere atualizar o cliente.

Este software é apenas um .exe com tres dlls na mesma pasta do executavel:

- libmysql.dll
- libpq.dll
- libpq721.dll

Para atualizar o cliente, só preciso destas dlls novas? Se sim, como encontrar as corretas, pois tentei baixar algumas, mas só piorou.

O software é feito em Delphi e tenho o fonte, preciso alterar algo neste fonte para atualizar o cliente?

Answer (score 0):

Me pareque que as libpq são para acesso a PostGree e não devem ser necessárias para acessar MySQL.

Como você já tentou somente copiar as DLLs novas e não funcionou, o seu EXE atual não pode acessar as novas DLLs, ou elas não são as corretas.

Considerando o parágrafo anterior e que as novas DLLs são corretas, no caso mais simples, atualize apenas a libmysql.

Se não funcionar, no próximo caso, ainda simples, será necessário apenas compilar seu programa com as novas bibliotecas, para que o linker faça as ligações corretas. Se o programa compilar sem erros, muito provavelmente funcionará, do contrário pode precisar alguma alteração em código.

Não me lembro bem, mas acho que o servidor MySQL 5 pode ser configurado para aceitar a mesma segurança da versão 4, que pode ser uma outra alternativa caso a atualização do cliente não seja possível.

**Edição 2015-05-22:**
O protocolo, deve ser especificado no componente ZeosDBO, e é diferente para a versão 4 e 5 do Mysql. Para a versão 5, tente utilizar `<componente>.Protocol = 'mysqld-5'`. Se houver connectionString, não é o mesmo protocolo dela, é do componente mesmo, caixa de seleção.

Se o ZeosDBO não tiver esta opção, verifique se há atualização para o componente (http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/). Só que talvez tenha que verificar se continua compatível com o código.

Comment: Já mudei a senha para o formato antigo, mas não adiantou. No código do programa, ele não usa nenhuma referencia a versão do Mysql. Eu acredito que apenas atualizando as dlls deve resolver. A minha dúvida seria, como encontrar a dll correta?

Comment: Esqueci de comentar. O software usa o componente Zeos 5.4 para fazer as transações com o DB. Não encontrei nada concreto, mas será que esta versão do Zeos que não aceita o Msyql 5.6?

Comment: Editei a resposta, pode ser a propriedade `Protocol` do componente ZeosDOB.

Answer (score 0):

Se o banco é MySql, você só precisa da libmysql.dll.  Para ter compatibilidade teria que fazer um downgrade instalando o MySql Server 4 em sua máquina, após isso procure a dll libmysql.dll na pasta de instalação dele e coloque no lugar da que voce tem hoje. A configuração do componente ZConnection informando a versão correta do MySql também é importante.